# Show all registered visual studio code servers

Tags: vscode-remote

I tried to register a new visual studio code server instance and get the exception:

```
Reason: You've exceeded the 10 machine limit for the port fowarding service. Please remove other machines before trying to add this machine.
```

It is possible, that I reached the maximum amount of registrations because I use different systems and also register single systems more than one time. I use different registrations on single system to run vsc remote in different environments for different projects.

If I open the connection dialog in vsc, I see only 8 systems. Therefore 2 are missing, which I could unregistered, if I would know the names (can't remember it). Is there any possibly to get an overview of all registered server? Maybe in vsc or GitHub?

Already tried to open the dialog `Remote-Tunnel: connect to tunnel ...` in vsc and searched for the names. Used `code tunnel --help` and `code tunnel prune` on the remote systems. Search for it in the GitHub settings.

Comment: I also remove another server and still, it is not possible to add a new one.